# How to get a web app to permit files to be dragged and dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

Specifically, I just realized I can drag and drop files into my gmail to add them as attachments. I want to know how they made it so that files can be dropped into the web-page and processed.

Is there a library for this sort of thing?

Comment: HTML5 added the File API and each browser needs to be updated to support it. For example: http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/07/chrome-21-adds-new-drag-and-drop-tricks/

Comment: Cymen, please consider making your comment an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the latest desktop browsers support the HTML5 File API ([source](http://caniuse.com/dragndrop)). To get drag and drop support in the older browsers that don't support it, you would need to use flash.

This [tutorial](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/) is a good starting point, if you'd like to try and implement HTML5 drag and drop on your site.